# How to create a symbolic/soft link to a file not a folder

Tags: windows, symbolic-link

Im trying to create a symbolic link to a text file with directory:

```
C:\users\me\textfile.txt
```

where the shortcut is in the same folder (for simplicity)

using command:

```
mklink /d "C:\users\me\textfileshortcut.txt" "C:\users\me\textfile.txt"
```

but this just creates a folder with the name `textfileshortcut.txt` and not a shortcut to a file.

What am i doing wrong?

Note: I am using windows 7

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are using the directory `/d` flag. Remove this flag and you will make links to files rather than directories.

For example,

`mklink "C:\users\me\textfileshortcut.txt" "C:\users\me\textfile.txt"`

Source: (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194.aspx)